# Combined touch plus swipe gestures and TalkBack

Tags: accessibility, talk-back, touch, gestures, multi-touch

I would like to know whether on Android devices it is possible to input a combined touch plus swipe gesture.

For instance, I could touch with one or more fingers with the left hand, and simultaneously swipe left to right or right to left with the right hand.

As an application, with TakBack, this could be used, with one finger plus swipe left to right or right to left, to skip forward or backward one word while text is being read, with two fingers plus swipe left to right or right to left, to skip forward or backward one sentence while text is being read, and three fingers plus swipe to toggle pausing while text is being read.

I think, this could be significantly useful in improving usability of TalkBack for blind users.

When will this be available in Android?

Thanks.